# Cut with different 'breaks' arguments for each value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column of values on [0,1] (`df$Estimate`) and four columns (`df$V1-4`) of break values; each row is of the form `c(0, [somevalue], 0.8, 1)`. For each value in `df$Estimate`, I want to pass its row's values of `df$V1-4` to the cut function.

Code to replicate the example with a for-loop version of a solution:

```
nrow <- 10
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Estimate = runif(nrow), V1 = 0, 
                 V2 = runif(nrow, 0.1, 0.75), 
                 V3 = 0.8, V4 = 1)
bins <- vector(length = nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    bins[i] <- cut(df$Estimate[i], df[i, grep("V[0-9]", colnames(df))])
}
```

So I've got a kludgey solution, but what's the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the right way, but a possibility is to use `findInterval` :

```
apply(df, 1, function(v) { findInterval(v[1], v[2:5]) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `apply` solution using `cut` still:

```
 apply(df,1,function(x) cut(x[1],x[-1],labels = FALSE))
```